# Add and compare datetime values in ArrayList of a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, datetime, hashmap

I have a HashMap of type `String,List<Date>` in Java. Now what I want to do is for each key I want to find the total time(by adding the individual Time in each Date) and then neglect the key with the highest time. If there are two keys with same highest time then neglect the key whose key is less in integer form(key 100 is less than 101). For rest of the keys I want to find resultant cost by multiplying the time(in seconds) by 50 if time is less than 3 minutes(so if time is `00:02:59` then multiply `179 by 50`) or if more than 3 minutes then multiply time(in rounded to next minutes) by 80(so if time is `00:03:01` then multiply `4 by 80`).

A sample of HashMap data that I have is:

```
100 [Thu Jan 01 00:05:01 EST 1970]
101 [Thu Jan 01 00:01:07 EST 1970, Thu Jan 01 00:05:03 EST 1970]
102 [Thu Jan 01 00:07:11 EST 1970]
103 [Thu Jan 01 00:02:59 EST 1970, Thu Jan 01 00:04:38 EST 1970, Thu Jan 01 00:06:16 EST 1970]
```

In the above example you can see key `103` has the highest time(adding `00:02:59`,`00:04:38`,`00:06:16`) so I will neglect all values from this key in my final cost calculation. For rest of keys I want to calculate my final cost by following the rules I mentioned above - so for example for key `101` total cost will be `67*50 (00:01:07 is less than 3 minutes) + 6 * 80 (00:05:03 is more than 3 minutes)`.

**UPDATE: The code that I have so far after some suggestions is:**

```
long totalCost = map.values().stream()
    .mapToLong(dates -> dates.stream().mapToLong(Date::getTime).sum())
    .sorted().limit(map.size() - 1)
    .map(Myclass::getCost).sum();

    System.out.println(totalCost);
```

One issue with this code is that suppose if there are two keys with same total time, in that case I want to neglect the key whose key value is numerically less(as in key 100 is less than 101). The code so far neglects the first available key after sorting (in line `sorted().limit(map.size() - 1)`). How to modify it to check if there are multiple keys with same maximum time than neglect the one with lowest numerical value.

**Note:** The datetime value in each value has a date component which remains same as Thu Jan 01  EST 1970 and is of no relevance in calculation.

Comment: iterate over entryset ... find greatest value and ignore it along with storing rest of the entries in another map...iterate again and calculate the cost.. as simple as that...

Comment: `Date` seems to be the wrong data type. `java.time.Duration` might be a better choice.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I have updated my post above to indicate the code that I have for now.

Comment: @DanglingPiyush can you provide me an example using the sample data  I have posted above?

Comment: @user2966197 please read java.util.Map implementation if you are not aware how to use Entryset on a map..   It's not that hard give it a try... basically you can iterate over map (key and value both) using entryset.. I would suggest figure out the rest yourself..

Comment: @DanglingPiyush as far as I can tell OP makes no use of the keys in the calculation so entrySet is not appropriate. Only values are required.

Answer (score 1):

## Right types

You are using all the wrong data types.

### `Integer`

Your key of type String is really an integer number as you say we should compare its values numerically. So use [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class in the first place.

### `Duration`

You are abusing the [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class, a date-time value, as a span-of-time. Firstly, avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes entirely and use their replacements, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Secondly use a span-of-time class for representing a span of time. In your particular case, that would mean the [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

The `Duration` class can parse and generate String representations of its values in the [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). For example, `PT1M30S` means “one and a half minutes”.

Avoid using a time-of-day format to represent a span of time as it creates ambiguity; the ISO 8601 format is easy to parse, easy to read, avoids ambiguity, and is designed for purpose.

### Not a `Map`

Your use of a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is becoming awkward as you are really working with three values rather than a pair:

- Integer (the key, an identifier)
- List (a collection of spans of time)
- Integer (a sum of the “cost” values generated for each duration)

## Custom class

So create a class with these three values. The last is a read-only value, either calculated on-the-fly or cached for better performance.

Here is an example class. I named it `Event` as no name is given in the Question. Caution: Use this source code entirely at your own risk. Not thread-safe. Not tested. Not guaranteed in any way.

This class dynamically recalculates the cost of its list of `Duration` objects on-the-fly. Caching would improve performance is used a very large number of times or with a very large amount of data.

This class implements `Comparable` with a custom method that accounts for the primary rule of comparing the cost and then secondarily comparing the id number where cost is equal.

Being `Comparable` means you can easily sort a collection of these `Event` objects. Then ignore the first/last item to handle your rule of omitting the highest scoring event.

```
package example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Example class posted on Stack Overflow:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/39399156/642706
 *
 * Caution: NOT thread-safe. NOT tested. NOT guaranteed.
 *
 * © 2016 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used in accordance with the ISC
 * license: https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque.
 */
public class Event implements Comparable<Event> {

    private Integer id;
    private List<Duration> durations;

    // Constants
    static final public long COST_PER_SECOND = 50L;
    static final public long COST_PER_MINUTE = 80L;

    // Constructor.
    public Event ( Integer id , List<Duration> durations ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.durations = durations;
    }

    public Integer getId () {
        return this.id;
    }

    public List<Duration> getDurations () {
        List<Duration> defensiveCopyOfList = new ArrayList<> ( this.durations );
        return defensiveCopyOfList;
    }

    public Long getCost () {
        // Calculate the cost of each Duration in our list.
        // Perhaps cache this calculated value for better performance.
        long sum = 0;
        for ( Duration duration : this.durations ) {
            long c = this.calculateCostOfDuration ( duration );
            sum = ( sum + c );
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private long calculateCostOfDuration ( Duration duration ) {
        long result = 0;
        long countMinutes = duration.toMinutes ();
        long limit = 3L; // We care if the duration is under 3 minutes (or else is 3 or more minutes).
        if ( countMinutes < limit ) {
            result = ( duration.getSeconds () * Event.COST_PER_SECOND );
        } else if ( countMinutes >= limit ) {
            // Round up to next minute. If ane even multiple of 60 seconds, then use count of minutes. Otherwise add one.
            long m = ( duration.getSeconds () % 60 == 0 ) ? countMinutes : ( countMinutes + 1 );
            result = ( m * Event.COST_PER_MINUTE );
        } else {
            System.out.println ( "ERROR - Reached impossible ELSE condition." );
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo ( Event o ) {
        // Compare cost of each Event.
        // If cost is equal, then secondarily compare the id members so a '101' sorts before a '102.
        int c = this.getCost ().compareTo ( o.getCost () );
        if ( c == 0 ) {
            c = this.getId ().compareTo ( o.getId () );
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Event{ " + "id=" + id + " | durations=" + durations + " | cost=" + this.getCost () + " }";  // For debugging purposes.
    }

}
```

Example use of this class utilizing example data given in the Question.

```
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<> ( 4 );

List<Duration> d = new ArrayList<> ();
d.add ( Duration.parse ( "PT5M1S" ) );
events.add ( new Event ( 100 , d ) );

d = new ArrayList<> ();
d.add ( Duration.parse ( "PT1M7S" ) );
d.add ( Duration.parse ( "PT5M3S" ) );
events.add ( new Event ( 101 , d ) );

d = new ArrayList<> ();
d.add ( Duration.parse ( "PT7M11S" ) );
events.add ( new Event ( 102 , d ) );

d = new ArrayList<> ();
d.add ( Duration.parse ( "PT2M59S" ) );
d.add ( Duration.parse ( "PT4M38S" ) );
d.add ( Duration.parse ( "PT6M16S" ) );
events.add ( new Event ( 103 , d ) );

Collections.sort ( events );

System.out.println ( "events: \n" + events );
```

When run. Note the sorted order is now 100|102|101|103.

> [Event{ id=100 | durations=[PT5M1S] | cost=480 }, Event{ id=102 | durations=[PT7M11S] | cost=640 }, Event{ id=101 | durations=[PT1M7S, PT5M3S] | cost=3830 }, Event{ id=103 | durations=[PT2M59S, PT4M38S, PT6M16S] | cost=9910 }]

Comment: I have modified my current code and posted one issue that I am having in my post above